# iCarousel: scrolling speed is directly-proportional to "spacing" (distance) between items?

Tags: ios, scroll, uiscrollview, distance, icarousel

[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

I took the linear `iCarousel` example and tried to decrease the distance between items. I used the following code in my delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value {

    switch (option) {

        case iCarouselOptionSpacing:
            return 0.25;
            break;
        default:
            return value;
            break;
    }
}
```

By default `spacing` is equal to 1 and works normally. If I change it to a lower value then the scrolling speed is decreased by the same value.

I tried to increase `offsetMultiplier` param but it increases the scrolling speed on swipe gestures too (it usually works normally but in this case it becomes too fast).

So how to break these dependencies and change the space between items only?

Answer (score -1):

### Try this it worked for me (Add this in your controller)

```
- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    //usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
    return 240;
}
```